# Anyone has an idea about which zombie is this?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I was playing Plants VS. Zombies 2 Chinese Version, and I went on to play on Penny's Pursuit as a new event started, and while I got on the level 3, I found this zombie:

[image]

It does not appear in Almanac or in the beginning where all zombies of the level are seen while choosing seeds for the level. The zombie basically messes around going anywhere all the way up to the lawn mower by moving both horizontally and vertically, it won't cause any harm to the plants, heals the zombies, randomly drops silver and gold coins, and when you defeat it, it spams silver and gold coins on the location he died.

To mention again, it's not regular PvZ 2, it's the Chinese version of it.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a God of Wealth zombie according to this [Wiki page](https://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/God_of_Wealth), which does:

> He attacked by firing gold pieces upward, which could rain down on a random plant. When killed, he dropped six gold coins and a red packet. This red packet, when opened, could give the player items, Puzzle Pieces for Big Wave Beach related plants, item Puzzle Pieces, costume Puzzle Pieces for Big Wave Beach plants, as well as Lord Bamboo.